# JPQL returning no results when one of the fields is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a query which looks like this:
`@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entity e")` which returns all of the entities (currently 15). I want to only select certain fields to make the query far more memory efficient (has lots of embedded entities I don't need).

I have 2 many to one relationships, a and b, of which one is normally null and the other has a value. If I do `@Query(value = "SELECT e.a FROM Entity e")` I get the 10 results where a is not null, and when I do `@Query(value = "SELECT e.b FROM Entity e")` I get the other 5 where b is not null. However if I do `@Query(value = "SELECT e.a, e.b FROM Entity e")` I get 0 results back. I would assume it would all 15, returning it as a `List<Object[]>`. Why does this happen, and can I change it so `@Query(value = "SELECT e.a, e.b FROM Entity e")` returns all of the entities?

Answer (score 2):

If `e.a` and `e.b` are entities you need `left join`

```
select a, b from Entity e left join e.a a left join e.b b
```

Comment: Mark as answered, please.